# Azure SQL Database Created via export dbo not enabled for user

Tags: database, azure

I cannot seem to enable DBO user on database. As Admin I can see all DB tables
But when I create a Login and user using this code.

```
CREATE LOGIN[ME] WITH password='Mypass'
GO
CREATE USER [ME] FOR LOGIN [ME] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo] 
GO
--Next connect/switch to the database you want the new user for. Create a user in that database

CREATE USER [ME] FOR LOGIN [ME] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'ME';
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'ME';
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'ME';
GO

GRANT CONNECT TO [public]

GRANT EXECUTE TO [ME]
```

The dbo user is not enabled **can anyone explain how to enable**? as most attempts even as Admin do not have permission to effect the dbo user.
[image: dbo not enabled in azure]

Picture shows both admin and new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AUMC from codeplex by adding loginmanager to user then removing. This worked but don't know why!